# Accessing variables or functions dynamically in React JS Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I have a list of items like this:

```
const bookContents = [

    <BookStart />,
    <BookForword />,
    <BookIntro />,
    <BookFirstchapter />,
    <BookSeconchapter />,
    <BookEpilogue />,
    <BookBackpage />
];
```

and I can access the first item by just writing this:

```
return(
<div>
    {bookContents[0]}
</div>
)
```

and access the number of items by just doing this:

```
return(
<div>
    {bookContents.length}
</div>
)
```

However I need to access it dynamically. All I have is this

```
myDialogue.Book
```

which equals the string "bookContents".

So how do I use `myDialogue.Book` to access `const bookContents` ?

Is there a way I can tell react that when I write `myDialogue.Book` which equals the string `"bookContents"` I am specifically targetting `const bookContents`?

Once I have this bit sorted I can move on with quite a big piece of work which is unfortunately being held up because of this.

Any help really would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: And where does `curDialogue` come from?

Comment: I have simplified my question so curDialogue isn't a part of the code as it's irrelevant and making the question more difficult for people to work out.

Comment: Not sure i understand the question... Whats the reason for storing components in an array? If you want to render different components dynamically, store them in an object and pull them out via bracket notation with a key

Comment: Hi Kyle the components are stored like that because that's what I've been given to work with unfortunately. So really I just need an answer to the above question rather than suggestions of reworking it at this stage. I'm really hoping there is a quick solution to this. Do you have any ideas of being able to access the const like that? Thanks.